# Unit Test a typescript controller that implement social login with passportJS

Tags: typescript, express, jestjs, passport.js, ts-jest

I am having a problem which is taking my head. I am implementing social login with Facebook and Google using passportJS, `passport-facebook-token` and `passport-google-oauth20` inside my node-express API.

The issue arises with unit testing; I didn't find how to make integrations.

Here is what I tried:

#### Routes

```
router.post(
  '/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook-token', { session: false }),
  authCtrl.socialLogin,
);
router.post('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { session: false }), authCtrl.socialLogin);
```

The route is using a passportJS middleware that I configured as follow:

```
passport.use(
  'facebook-token',
  new FacebookTokenStrategy(
    {
      clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
      clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    },
    async (_accessToken: string, _refreshToken: string, profile, done) => {
      done(null, profile);
    },
  ),
);

passport.use(
  'google',
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: GOOGLE_APP_ID,
      clientSecret: GOOGLE_APP_SECRET,
    },
    async (_accessToken: string, _refreshToken: string, profile, done) => {
      done(undefined, profile);
    },
  ),
);
```

#### Controller

Here is the way my controller looks like

```
public async socialLogin(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const { provider, displayName, emails, photos }: any = req.user;
      const profile = {
        username: displayName.replace(' ', '_').toLowerCase(),
        email: emails ? emails[0].value : null,
        image: photos[0].value,
      };

      console.log(req.user);

      User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { 'profile.username': profile.username, 'profile.email': profile.email },
        { provider, profile, isLoggedIn: true, isAdmin: false },
        { new: true, upsert: true },
        (err, data: any) => {
          if (err) return helper.getServerError(res, err.message);
          const { _id, profile, isAdmin } = data;
          const { email } = profile;
          const token = helper.generateToken({ _id, email, isAdmin });
          return helper.getResponse(res, httpStatus.CREATED, { token, data });
        },
      );
      return helper.getResponse(res, httpStatus.CREATED, { data: profile });
    } catch (error) {
      return helper.getServerError(res, error.message);
    }
  }
```

`const { provider, displayName, emails, photos }: any = req.user;`

In brief, I have to receive the provider, displayName, emails, and photos from the `user` object which is naturally returned by the passport middleware `authenticate()` method. You can look back at the route definition to understand.

#### Unit test

As I am using jest to unit-test the controller, I went with the approach of mocking the response and request so that I can pass the `user` object to the request. I tried to use the mocking utilities from jest, I was not able to properly mock the express request and response, so tried to use different third-party libraries, like [jest-express](https://github.com/jameswlane/jest-express) that I found so interesting

Here is how my test looks like:

```
describe(Auth.prototype.socialLogin, () => {
    let response: any;
    let request: any;

    beforeEach(() => {
      response = new Response();
    });

    afterAll(() => {
      response.resetMocked();
      request.resetMocked();
    });

    it('should create a new user', async () => {
      const requestMock: any = {
        user: {
          provider: 'facebook-token',
          displayName: 'user name',
          emails: [{ value: 'username@mail.com' }],
          photos: [{ value: 'image.jpg' }],
        },
      };

      request = new Request(requestMock);
      await authCtrl.socialLogin(request, response);
      expect(response.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(201);
    });
  });
```

#### Problem

When I run the test, I am getting this response.

[image]

It is clearly showing that the controller is running but it is falling on the catch block that supposes to respond with a 500 status to mean bad request.

So I really want help, if there is a place I am doing things wrong or any documentation that can help me to efficiently mock express response and request.